# Save variable names of dataframe (tibble) as vector

Tags: r, dataframe

My raw excel database exists of over 200 variables. I only want to include some variables, but I want to make an evaluated decision on which ones I want to import to R.

My question is: How can I create a vector with all variables names from a tibble, so that I can use that vector to decide which ones to hold and which ones to drop?

```
 # Example dataset
 df <- tibble(education = c("Low", "Medium", "High", "Low", "Medium", "High", "High"),
                 wellbeing = c(7, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 5),
                 gender = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)

 # Preferred result
 vector <- c("education", "wellbeing", "gender")
```

Comment: ``names(df)`` ?

Comment: Oh my, I feel stupid... Yes, of course :). Thank you!